# t3lib_div::_GP work in Typo3 6.2?

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I use a new typo3 version 6.2, but i think don't work anymore.
$myVars = t3lib_div::_GP('tx_myextenson_pi1');

Is there a substitute for this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In TYPO3 6.x `t3lib_div` is marked deprecated but still working (it's removed in 7.x finally) the same as many other well known - old fashioned classes in TYPO3 API!

You can/should use `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('foo')` instead (`GeneralUtility::_GET('foo')` - with proper import).

Take a look into `typo3/sysext/core/Migrations/Code/LegacyClassesForIde.php` which is just some kind of *bridge*, between pre-7 and after-7 API of TYPO3.

Comment: Thank you! i want to fix this project migration. i tried your solution but the variable i get is still empty,
<iframe class="no-border full-width-height" src="index.php?type=1296727025&amp;tx_myextenson_pi1[productID]=245"></iframe>

Comment: You must to debug what arrives to your action compare `t3lib_div::_GP('tx_myextenson_pi1')` vs `GeneralUtility::_GET('tx_myextenson_pi1')` vs `$_GET['tx_myextenson_pi1']` - as mentioned all these methods are valid and you should have some input on them... BTW, maybe your plugin is cached and without cHash it doesn't read additional params? add `&no_cache=1` param into your URL to check it

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i have made a debug on it and this is the result that i had :

Comment: Debug of _POST
EMPTY!

Debug of _GET
type 1296727025
no_cache 1

Debug of REQUEST_METHOD
|GET|

Debug of QUERY_STRING
|type=1296727025&no_cache=1|

Debug of REQUEST_URI
|/product-page/?type=1296727025&no_cache=1|

The parameters of my extension isn't there.
But when i take a look of the src of the iFrame like this :
<iframe class="no-border full-width-height" src="index.php?type=1296727025&amp;tx_productmanager_pi1=245&amp;no=51&amp;no_cache=1"></iframe>

So if the parameter is not in the debug ?